# MS Project - Multi-year Inflation

Tags: ms-project, planning, pm-software, resource-planning, ms-project-2016

I am managing a 3 year project in a country where the average annual inflation rate is 12%.   Instead of going through every item and entering "+12%" into the cost rate table for each item, is there a way  the rate increasing automatically for all resources over the 3 years in MS Project Professional 2016?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and most repeatable way to do this is with a macro/vba procedure. Here's some code that John - Project created and shared on msdn some years ago ([VBA Macro Help - Cost Rate Tables](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9ca80a49-6e2d-4ac4-9333-6cab03c428ef/vba-macro-help-cost-rate-tables?forum=project2010custprog)).

Option Compare Text

Sub NOVA_Rates()

Dim r As Resource

For Each r In ActiveProject.Resources

```
'jump around blank lines on Resource Sheet

If Not r Is Nothing Then

    'only do this if resource is labor type

    If r.Type = pjResourceTypeWork Then

        'first clear all pay rate data

        'Note: this is necessary if the macro is run a 2nd time with

        'the same data. Additional code is necessary to add new data

        'to existing pay rate tables and clearing may not be necessary.

        For i = 1 To 5

            'cycle through each of the 5 rate tables

            Set pr = r.CostRateTables(i).PayRates

            pr(1).StandardRate = 0

            pr(1).OvertimeRate = 0

            pr(1).CostPerUse = 0

            'clearing must be done in reverse order

            If pr.Count > 1 Then

                For j = pr.Count To 2 Step -1

                    pr(j).Delete

                Next j

            End If

        Next i

        'set new object for "B" table only

        Set pr = r.CostRateTables("B").PayRates

        'add new rate data based on Resource Text1 field

        If InStr(1, r.Text1, "Proj") > 0 Then

            pr.Add "7/2/2011", "$1/h", "$5/h", "$0"

        ElseIf InStr(1, r.Text1, "elec") > 0 Then

            pr.Add "7/2/2011", "$2/h", "$6/h", "$0"

        ElseIf InStr(1, r.Text1, "mech") > 0 Then

            pr.Add "7/2/2011", "$3/h", "$7/h", "$0"

        End If

    End If

End If
```

Next r

End Sub

Comment: Everything below the hyperlink belongs together in a single module in project vba.  I don't know how to control that here.